# Webview inside a viewpager

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-viewpager

I have viewpager and there is webview inside, the webview has swipe capability then when I swipe the webview it changes the whole viewpager, but I want if the swipe in the webview is finished then it changes the viewpager here is mycode

Pager adapter

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    return pageModels.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view==object;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.singlepage,container,false);
    webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.setScrollContainer(true);
    webView.bringToFront();
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    String readerContent = null;
    File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+File.separator+"check.html");
    Log.d("readerContent",readerContent);
    webView.loadUrl("http://192.168.0.108/book");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    ((ViewPager) container).addView(view);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((View)object);
}
public String getString(InputStream i) throws IOException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = i.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        result.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    return result.toString("UTF-8");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create custom ViewPager to prevent swipe.
Second, using WebView's javascript bridge to communicate native java code.
Briefly, js code might set your ViewPager swipeable or not.

---

+) When you inside html page reached end of swipe, call custom js function to notify native viewpager can be swipeable.